# how to get check/uncheck javascript working with asp components

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to create a set of check boxes linked to a dataset, with a header checkbox that checks or un-checks everything.

I found and example of this in the following blog https://www.webcodeexpert.com/2016/01/check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-in-aspnet.html which uses some javascript to achieve this.

When I try this myself everything works until I try and change the checkboxes from `<input type="checkbox" id="chkHeader" class="header" />` to `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server" Text="All" CssClass="header" />`. Any reason any of you can see why this won't work with asp components?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var chkAll = $('.header').click(function () {
            //Check header and item's checboxes on click of header checkbox
            chkItem.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
            });
        var chkItem = $(".item").click(function () {
            //If any of the item's checkbox is unchecked then also uncheck header's checkbox
            chkAll.prop('checked', chkItem.filter(':not(:checked)').length == 0);
            });
        });
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>AAUICL DSAR Tool</title>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


                  <asp:GridView ID="grdEmp" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>                         
                            <input type="checkbox" id="chkHeader" class="header" />
  <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server" Text="All" CssClass="header" />--%>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>                           
                            <input type="checkbox" id="chkItems" class="item" />
   <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="chkItems" runat="server" CssClass="item" />--%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employee Name" DataField="EmployeeName" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Code" DataField="EmployeeCode" />                    
                    
                    
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Age" DataField="Age" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
</form>
```

Server side ASP side code for completeness:

```
using System.Data;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGridview();
        }
    }
    protected void BindGridview()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //Add Columns to datatable
        dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeId", typeof(Int32));
        dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeCode", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(Int32));
        //Adding rows and data
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "Ajay", "EMP0001",22);
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Irfan", " EMP0002",21);
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "Hrithik", " EMP0003",24);
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "Ranbir", " EMP0004",26);
        dt.Rows.Add(5, "Salman", " EMP0005",25);       
        //Bind datatable to gridview
        grdEmp.DataSource = dt;
        grdEmp.DataBind();
    }
```

---

Below is the `myItemCheck` javascript function I wrote to supplement Albert D. Kallal's answer:

```
    function myitemcheck(btn) {
        var bolChecked = $(btn).is(':checked')
        MyTable = $('#grdEmp')
        MyCheckBoxs = MyTable.find('input:checkbox')

        var setHead = bolChecked

        if (setHead) {
            var i = 0
            MyCheckBoxs.each(function () {
                if (i != 0) {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked') != bolChecked) {
                        setHead = false
                    }
                }
                i++
            })
        }

        var i = 0
        MyCheckBoxs.each(function () {
            if (i == 0) {
                $(this).prop('checked', setHead)
            }
            i++
        })
    }
```

It is called by  `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkItems" runat="server" onclick="myitemcheck(this)"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, say with this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="grdEmp" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            width="30%" GridLines="None" ClientIDMode="Static"
            cssclass="table table-hover table-striped">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>                         
                      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server" Text="- All" onclick="myheadcheck(this)" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>                           
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkItems" runat="server"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employee Name" DataField="EmployeeName" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Code" DataField="EmployeeCode" />                                                           
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Age" DataField="Age" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

  <script> 
      function myheadcheck(btn) {
          var bolChecked = $(btn).is(':checked')

          // now set all check boxes
          MyTable = $('#grdEmp')
          MyCheckBoxs = MyTable.find('input:checkbox')              
          MyCheckBoxs.each(function () {
              $(this).prop('checked', bolChecked)
          })
   }
  </script>
```

I have NEVER been a fan of using document ready by some magic act to do selecting of the dom WHEN plain jane clean code can be written.

Note that I did use client id mode static for the gv name - but that just made the jquery selector easy to write.

We select the GV, then select check boxes by type, and then set them based on the value of the header check box click.

We get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - this seems much much nicer - I've also added a `myItemCheck` function to check/uncheck the "All" checkbox dependent on the state of all the other Item checkboxes. It's too large for this comment, so I'll add it to my original question. I suspect there may be a more elegant way to write it, but javascript is not a language I know very well!